# Fetch JSON data from a file

Tags: javascript, json

I got a very simple txt file in JSON format:

```
{
  "menu": "File1",
  "bday": [
      {
          "name": "teo",
          "date":"22"
      },
      {
          "name": "john",
          "date": "9"
      },
      {
          "name": "maria",
          "date": "15"
      }
   ]
}
```

All I want is to just fetch the data and print them. Like:

```
teo : 22
john:9

...etc...
```

I don't care about this. I just want to fetch the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is plainly [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.developer.com/lang/jscript/article.php/3596836/Speeding-Up-AJAX-with-JSON.htm), which is multi-browser compatible JavaScript without need for a library. You can always create your own library for some backward-compatibility.

Comment: AJAX, as we know it, without all the bells and whistles that come with libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Put the [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) in a file on your server (for example, `data.js`) and then use jQuery to fetch the file. Something like this:

```
var json;
$.getJSON("data.js", function(data){
    json = data;
});
```

Comment: thnx rcravens but i dont want jQuery or any other lib. is this possible or must be on a server ?

Comment: Javascript has no native filesystem type routines. Your only options to load it into JS is to embed it into the same file that the JS is loaded from, or have it served up via AJAX.